# how to pass single quote around string in batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file

Calling a sql script from batch file as follows

```
@script.sql "pass" "primary_key_1"
```

The calling script is appearing as

```
insert into values(pass,primary_key_1)
```

I want to appear  as

```
insert into values('pass','primary_key_1')
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened, for example, when you tried to pass `"'pass'"`?

Comment: @mathguy   INSERT INTO XML_AUDIT VALUES(Businessl,Progress,SYSTIMESTAMP) still same issue. I want to single quote variable which I pass

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the script with the parameters enclosed with double and single quotes or only with single quotes:

```
@echo off
echo INSERT INTO VALUES(%~1, %~2)
pause
```

Or if you are calling it without the single quotes:

```
@echo off
echo INSERT INTO VALUES('%~1', '%~2')
pause
```

Correct me, if there was something I misunderstood and feel free to ask questions!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function

```
create or replace FUNCTION           "SQL_QUOTE" 
(
   p_str        IN VARCHAR2
) return VARCHAR2
is
BEGIN
  return '''' ||  p_str ||'''';
END;
```

Usage:

```
select 'This is a ' || sql_quote('quoted-string')  || ' in a string;' from dual;
```

thus your line becomes

```
insert into values(sql_quote('pass'),sql_quote('primary_key_1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If script.sql where:

```
INSERT INTO <some_table> VALUES ('&1', '&2');
```

Then

calling script.sql from SQL*Plus like so:

```
@script.sql 'pass' 'primary_key_1'
```

should yield the desired results.

Calling it from an OS Command prompt:

```
sqlplus user/password@db @script.sql "pass" "primary_key_1"
```

should also have the desired result.