# sql file fetching value without quote

Tags: sql, batch-file, oracle10g

```
@echo off
REM Build YYYYMMDD_hhmmss format date/time stamp for new file name
set Stamp=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-10,2%%DATE:~-7,2%_%TIME:~0,8%
set Stamp=%Stamp::=%
set Stamp=%Stamp: =0%
set data_file=D:\Oracle\XML\Dump\XMLBusiness-%Stamp%.xml
set log_file=D:\Oracle\XML\Log\XMLBusiness-%Stamp%.log
set SUBJECT_AREA='ENITITY'
set STATUS='COMPLETED'



exit | sqlplus -S xx/yy@database @"C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\XML\insert_audit_table.sql" %SUBJECT_AREA %STATUS% "SYSTIMESTAMP"  >  %log_file%
```

I am using above code to pass value from batch file to sql but I am getting this error

```
old   1: INSERT INTO XML_AUDIT VALUES(&1,&2,&3)
new   1: INSERT INTO XML_AUDIT VALUES(BUSINESS_ENTITY,COMPLETED,SYSTIMESTAMP)
INSERT INTO XML_AUDIT VALUES(BUSINESS_ENTITY,COMPLETED,SYSTIMESTAMP)
                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Please help me in this. How can i enclose this in single quote

Comment: This is a way better question than the one you have asked 2 hours ago! You got your script, you got some real ouput! Good improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand your question completely but as per Error message, it cannot insert text as you gave. You should use single quotes for it. Make sure the values are coming as below

`INSERT INTO XML_AUDIT VALUES('BUSINESS_ENTITY','COMPLETED',SYSTIMESTAMP)`

Comment: He asked for the way to do so at the end of his question... This exactly is his problem as well as in [his other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858687/how-to-pass-single-quote-around-string-in-batch-file) this morning